# An example of a non-invariant measure on a compact Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, invariance, compact-manifolds, haar-measure

I would like to construct a non-invariant measure on a compact Lie group but I'm not sure what is allowed and what the consequences are. Take the simplest example of $SO(2)$. The unnormalized invariant measure is 
$$
d\mu=d\phi.
$$ 
for $0\leq\phi\leq2\pi$. So the integral of a function on a circle with this measure remains the same as one moves around. So far so good.

QUESTIONS

1. How much can I modify $d\mu$ to still have a legitimate (non-invariant) measure on $S^1$? How about 
   $$
   d\eta=\phi d\phi
   $$
   The invariance is broken $d\eta\to d\eta'=(\phi-a)d\phi$ so the integral of a function on $S^1$ will depend on $a$ as well as its normalization. Something else bad happened I can't see? Is it a legitimate measure for $SO(2)$?
2. Suppose that I am interested in the probabilistic interpretation of the non-invariant measure. It does not preserve the normalization of a function I'm integrating over (the normalization depends on $a$). Can I still use this measure to randomly and uniformly choose points on the circle? For example $d\eta$ `favors' some point over the others but it looks like I can counter the bias just by writing
   $$
   d\eta=1/2d(\phi^2),
   $$
   set $x=\phi^2$ so $\sqrt{x}=\pm\phi$ and choose $x$ uniformly and randomly. So it looks like a complicated it way of undoing non-invariance but other than that the question is: Can I in this way use a non-invariant measure to randomly and uniformly pick points on $S^1$?
3. If nothing is really wrong, how about more complicated compact Lie groups. For $SU(2)$ the invariant measure is
   $$d\mu=\sin{\beta}\cos{\beta}\ d\beta\ d\psi\ d\phi.$$
   Can I modify it to
   $$d\eta=\sin^6{\beta}\cos^3{\beta}\ d\beta\ d\psi\ d\phi$$
   and still choose the group elements uniformly and at random?

Comment: If you want an example: on arbitrary group you can multiply a Haar measure by an arbitrary nonegative function (if you want you can take a function $f$ s.t. its integral is equal to $1$ so your measure remains a probabilistic one). If this function is not invariant then the measure also will not be invariant.

Comment: Also you can take a discrete $\delta$-measure at identity. It is also not invariant.

Comment: Ok great, that's what I thought. So if there is nothing wrong with my two examples of $d\eta$ can I also use it to choose a group element uniformly and at random (my Q3)? The direction I'm heading is that one can read 'choose a unitary transformation according the the Haar measure'. I don't quite understand the need for Haar (when choosing a group element by picking points from a group manifold).

Comment: Just take a probability measure whose support is not the whole group (you can find one as soon as $G\neq\{1\}$, e.g., a Dirac measure).

Comment: @YCor  Could you elaborate? To achieve what exactly?

Comment: A non-invariant measure. Anyway what I said was already said in other comments.

Comment: @YCor Understood. So why so much emphasis on invariant measures (in the described context)? Of course, I see that otherwise the invariant measures are very useful and somewhat natural - the example I gave for $SO(2)$ is ugly in some sense. Who would use it to chart the circle?

Comment: Invariant measure are useful as reference measures, but considering general measures is important anyway.